# Citation in Brackets after definition/theorem

Tags: citing

I am currently trying to achieve the following result: I have defined a definition environment using `amsthm`. Using this, one can give additional information about the definition using brackets as follows:

```
\begin{def}[additional information]
...
\end{def}
```

I want to use this additional information for a citation. I have already learned that one can cite as follows `\parencite[Section ...]{1}` when wanting to specify where exactly the cited result is stated.

However, this does not work in the additional information in the definition (I think because LaTeX is overwhelmed with the two sets of squared brackets).

Is there a way to get the wanted result?

Comment: Please show us a short compilable TeX code what you have tried so far. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing...

Answer (score 0):

A MWE would be nice, but I’m pretty sure the issue here is the balancing of brackets. This is a problem I have faced many times, too. One solution is to enclose the content of the brackets in an extra pair of braces:

```
\begin{definition}[{See e.g. \cite[Section ...]{1}}]
...
\end{definition}
```

I chose the BibLaTeX command `\cite` rather than `\parencite` in order to avoid double parentheses (just a matter of aesthetics).

Also, you cannot use the environment name `def` for definitions, as defining `\begin{def}...\end{def}` would involve defining two commands with names `\def` and `\enddef`. And the command name `\def` is already taken (and should not be redefined!).